# Companion object for Set in Scala

Tags: scala, set, companion-object

From book 'Programming in Scala',doing this:

```
var jetSet = Set("Boeing", "Airbus")
```

invokes 'apply' on the companion object for scala.collection.immutable.Set,
which returns an instance of a default, immutable Set.

But isn't companion object defined for the class with same name, and scala.collection.immutable.Set is a trait and not a class.So how come we have companion object for a trait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala allows you to define a companion object for both traits and classes.

Try it:

```
trait Foo

object Foo {
    def apply(x: Int): Foo = new Foo { }
}
```

Ih this example the companion object returns an instance of type `Foo` that is implemented as an anonymous class that extends the trait.